# Gossip problem why 4?

Tags: graph-theory

Each of 10 friends knows some item of gossip not known to the others. They communicate by telephone, and in each call the two friends on the line share everything they have heard thus far. What is the smallest number of calls that can be made, such that by the end, everyone knows everything?

I came across this interesting problem today !

This is what i understood.To make the minimum number of calls.Consider it as a graph or an n-agon. Now,you'll move through the graph for n calls.

1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-1

10 calls,now 1 and 10 knows all the information.All other nodes will communicate with any of the two nodes and accept the data.Which means n+n-2=2*n-2(18 calls).

I thought this was minimum value.But found out that it is 2*n-4.

And the logic behind that is divide the group as 4 and 6.Now you'll have

f(4)=4
And f(6)=6.

Now,all the six people have to communicate with all the four people + 2 times so that everyone in the 6 people group will know all the data..which is 16 calls < 18 calls.

What i wanted to know is what is so special about 4 in this problem why after 4 every problem(n>4) depends on f(4) ? Why splitting 4 seperately ?

Comment: Maybe it's because $2n-4$ calls won't do the job if $n=2$ or $n=3$?

Comment: Is this the only reason ? Can you please prove it ? So that if i come across such problems in the future i may be able to use it !

Comment: You want me to **prove** that two calls won't work for three gossips?? Let's see. First gossip #1 chats with gossip #2, then #1 chats with #3. Now #1 and #3 know everything, but #2 doesn't know #3's gossip, so another call is needed.

Comment: Are you sure $f(6)=6$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple construction which shows that $f(n+1) \le f(n) + 2$. Let the newly added participant ($X$) make the first call (to a participant we shall call $Y$); then his gossip spreads along with $Y$'s gossip as the $n$ participants perform $f(n)$ calls; finally, any one of them calls $X$ with the full set of gossip.

The significance of $n=4$ is that it is the smallest set of participants which achieves the lower bound of $2n-4$ calls. This bound was proved by various people in 1971.